# Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

Tags: generics, swift

I have issue with following code:

```
func generic1<T>(name : String){
}

func generic2<T>(name : String){
     generic1<T>(name)
}
```

the *generic1(name)* result to compiler error "Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function"

Is any way to avoid this error? I can't change signature of generic1 function, therefore it should be (String) -> Void

Comment: Whats the point of using generic type here when it cannot be inferred for the context? If generic type is used only internally you should specify the type within the body of the function.

Comment: Is the placeholder type `T` used at all in `generic1()`? How would you *call* that function, so that the compiler can infer the type?

Comment: This is just sample from playground. I want use template parameter inside function, for example: func generic1<T>(name : String){ T.handle(name)
}

Comment: @Greyisf: But as mentioned in above comments, the compiles has to infer the type from the context of the function call. So even `generic1("SomeString")` already fails to compile. How can the compiler know what `T` should be in `T.handle()` ?

Comment: I hope that there is some way to call function like genetic1<blaClass>("SomeString")

Comment: Generics are not only for cases when the compiler can infer the context. Explictly specializing the function would allow other parts of the code to be infered. ex: `func foo<T>() -> T { ... }` that does something with an object `t` of type `T` and the return `t`. Explicitly specialising `T` would allow `t1` to be infereed in `var t1 = foo<T>()`. I wish there was a way to call functions these way too. C# allows it

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726937/how-do-i-call-a-generic-swift-function-when-none-of-the-arguments-provides-the-g is the same

Comment: On twitter this guy has the same problem too: https://twitter.com/dangerdave/status/490385202170982401

Comment: Bug reported [rdar://20583619](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6185198710423552)

Comment: I'm just ran into this too. It makes zero sense to create a generic function if you're forced to pass the type as a parameter. This has to be a bug right?!

Comment: @Nick Right, it's practically a bug in Swift. In all normal languages it just works, but not in Swift for crying out loud. And I hate it when they come up with special reasons why it is the way it is. It should just work, period.

Answer (score 205):

I also had this problem and I found a workaround for my case.

In this article the author has the same problem

https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/swift-programming-101-generics-practical-guide

So the problem seems to be, that the compiler needs to infer the type of T somehow. But it isn't allowed to simply use generic< type >(params...).

Normally, the compiler can look for the type of T, by scanning the parameter types because this is where T is used in many cases.

In my case it was a little bit different, because the return type of my function was T. In your case it seems that you haven't used T at all in your function. I guess you just simplified the example code.

So I have the following function

```
func getProperty<T>( propertyID : String ) -> T
```

And in case of, for instance

```
getProperty<Int>("countProperty")
```

the compiler gives me the error:

> Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

So, to give the compiler another source of information to infer the type of T from, you have to explicitly declare the type of the variable the return value is saved in.

```
var value : Int = getProperty("countProperty")
```

This way the compiler knows that T has to be an integer.

So I think overall it simply means that if you specify a generic function you have to at least use T in your parameter types or as a return type.

Comment: Is there a way to do that if there's no return value? i.e., `func updateProperty<T>( propertyID : String )`

Comment: I don't see why you would want to do that? Since you don't return anything, there is no benefit in declaring your function generic.

Comment: @ThottChief there is plenty of benefit e.g. if you're using/building keypaths, or getting type name as a string etc.

Comment: Great answer thanks. I wish this would work with `let value = foo() as? Type` so it could be used in a `if` or `guard` it the result is optional, but it doesn't...

Comment: @agirault So long as foo() returns an optional, e.g.`foo<T>() -> T?`, then `guard let value = foo() as SomeType?` will work, just not `as? SomeType`

Answer (score 88):

## Swift 5

Typically there are many ways to define generic functions. But they are based on condition that `T` must be used as a `parameter`, or as a `return type`.

```
extension UIViewController {
    class func doSomething<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return T()
    }

    class func doSomethingElse<T: UIView>(value: T) {
        // Note: value is a instance of T
    }

    class func doLastThing<T: UIView>(value: T.Type) {
        // Note: value is a MetaType of T
    }
}
```

After that, we must provide `T` when calling.

```
let result = UIViewController.doSomething() as UIImageView // Define `T` by casting, as UIImageView
let result: UILabel = UIViewController.doSomething() // Define `T` with property type, as UILabel
UIViewController.doSomethingElse(value: UIButton()) // Define `T` with parameter type, as UIButton
UIViewController.doLastThing(value: UITextView.self) // Define `T` with parameter type, as UITextView
```

Ref:

1. http://austinzheng.com/2015/01/02/swift-generics-pt-1/
2. https://dispatchswift.com/type-constraints-for-generics-in-swift-d6bf2f0dbbb2

Comment: Great answer to the general problem...since there are so many ways to fix it. I also realized `self.result = UIViewController.doSomething()` works on its own as long as you've typed the property when you declare it.

Comment: great answer explaining a lot of things.

Comment: Java `doLastThing<UITextView>()` becomes Swift `doLastThing(UITextView.self)`, which is...not the worst, at least.  Better than having to explicitly type complicated results.  Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: `doLastThing` did the trick for me, the most sane solution I found. Answer's author is an ape above humans.

Answer (score 23):

#### The solution is taking the class type as parameter (like in Java)

To let compiler know what type he is dealing with pass the class as argument

```
extension UIViewController {
    func navigate<ControllerType: UIViewController>(_ dump: ControllerType.Type, id: String, before: ((ControllerType) -> Void)?){
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) as! ControllerType
        before?(controller)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Call as:

```
self.navigate(UserDetailsViewController.self, id: "UserDetailsViewController", before: {
        controller in
        controller.user = self.notification.sender
    })
```

Comment: This is great and much better than the accepted answer. Please consider editing to remove the historical part, or at least put it below the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @DanRosenstark Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Although this works I don't think it's best practice. The reason is that now the function definition is making decisions about what to do if there's a problem with the cast. So, here you are just crashing if the cast fails. It's better to let the client decide what to do since this may vary by client. So, I'm going to down vote this answer for this reason.

Comment: @smileBot You mean the example is bad or the approach?

Comment: The approach. I think it's a general rule of programming to defer specialization when practical. This is part of the idea of understanding responsibility. It is not the function's responsibility to specialize the generic. This is the caller's responsiblity, since the function cannot know what all callers will need. If the function gets into this role then this limits the use of the function for no gain. You can generalize this to many coding problems. This single concept has helped me enormously.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a generic here since you have static types (String as parameter), but if you want to have a generic function call another you could do the following.

Using Generic methods

```
func fetchObjectOrCreate<T: NSManagedObject>(type: T.Type) -> T {
    if let existing = fetchExisting(type) {
       return existing
    }
    else {
        return createNew(type)
    }
}

func fetchExisting<T: NSManagedObject>(type: T.Type) -> T {
    let entityName = NSStringFromClass(type)
     // Run query for entiry
} 

func createNew<T: NSManagedObject>(type: T.Type) -> T {
     let entityName = NSStringFromClass(type)
     // create entity with name
}
```

Using a generic class (Less flexible as the generic can be defined for 1 type only per instance)

```
class Foo<T> {

   func doStuff(text: String) -> T {
      return doOtherStuff(text)
   }

   func doOtherStuff(text: String) -> T {

   }  

}

let foo = Foo<Int>()
foo.doStuff("text")
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that when you specify generic function you should specify some of the parameters of type T, like followed:

```
func generic1<T>(parameter: T) {
    println("OK")
}

func generic2<T>(parameter: T) {
    generic1(parameter)
}
```

and if you want to call handle() method, then you may do this by writing protocol, and specifying type constraint for T:

```
protocol Example {
    func handle() -> String
}

extension String: Example {
    func handle() -> String {
        return "OK"
    }
}

func generic1<T: Example>(parameter: T) {
    println(parameter.handle())
}

func generic2<T: Example>(parameter: T) {
    generic1(parameter)
}
```

so you may call this generic function with String:

```
generic2("Some")
```

and it will compile

Answer (score 3):

So far, my personal best practise used @orkhan-alikhanov 's answer. Today, when looking at SwiftUI and how `.modifier()` and the `ViewModifier` is implemented, I found another way (or is it more a workaround?)

Simply wrap the second function into a `struct`.

### Example:

If this one gives you the "Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function"

```
func generic2<T>(name: String){
     generic1<T>(name)
}
```

This one might help. Wrap the declaration of `generic1` into a `struct`:

```
struct Generic1Struct<T> {
    func generic1(name: String) {## do, whatever it needs with T ##}
}
```

and call it with:

```
func generic2<T>(name : String){
     Generic1Struct<T>().generic1(name: name)
}
```

### Remarks:

- I don't know if it helps in any possible case, when this error message occurs. I just know, that I was stuck many times when this came up. I do know, that this solution helped today, when the error-message came up.
- The way Swift handles Generics is for me still confusing.
- This example and the workaround with the `struct` is a good example. The workaround here has not a bit more information - but passes the compiler. Same information, but different results? Then something is wrong. If it is a compiler-bug it can get fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```swift
func generic1<T>(of type: T.Type, name: String) {
    switch type {
    case is String.Type:
        print("String generic")
    case is Int.Type:
        print("Int generic")
    default:
        print("\(type) generic")
    }
    print(name)
}

func generic2<T>(of type: T.Type, name: String) {
     generic1(of: T.self, name: name)
}

generic2(of: String.self, name: "hello")
// String generic
// hello
generic2(of: Int.self, name: "world")
// Int generic
// world
generic2(of: Float.self, name: "bye")
// Float generic
// bye
```

Since calling as `generic<T>()` is illegal in Swift,
This `generic(of: T.self)` usage is a workaround I found.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my generic class function `class func retrieveByKey<T: GrandLite>(key: String) -> T?`.

I could not call it `let a = retrieveByKey<Categories>(key: "abc")` where Categories is a subclass of GrandLite.

`let a = Categories.retrieveByKey(key:"abc")` returned GrandLite, not Categories. Generic functions do not infer type based on the class that calls them.

`class func retrieveByKey<T: GrandLite>(aType: T, key: String>) -> T?` gave me an error when I tried `let a = Categories.retrieveByKey(aType: Categories, key: "abc")` gave me an error that it could not convert Categories.Type to GrandLite, even though Categories is a subclass of GrandLite. HOWEVER...

`class func retrieveByKey<T: GrandLite>(aType: [T], key: String) -> T?` *did* work if I tried `let a = Categories.retrieveByKey(aType: [Categories](), key: "abc")` apparently an explicit assignment of a subclass does not work, but an implicit assigment using another generic type (array) does work in Swift 3.

Comment: To fix the error, you have to provide `aType` as an instance of `T`, instead of putting `Categories` itself. Ex: `let a = Categories.retrieveByKey(aType: Categories(), key: "abc")`. Another solution is define `aType: T.Type`. Then call the method as `let a = Categories.retrieveByKey(aType: Categories.self, key: "abc")`

Answer (score 0):

if you have a return value in your generic functions with a signature similar to

```
func anyServerLoadingEndEvent<Result>(
    result buildResult: @autoclosure () -> Result)
    -> ServerLoadingEndEvent<Result>
{
    ServerLoadingEndEvent(
        param1: ...,
        result: buildResult()
    )
}

func anyServerUploadingEndEvent<Result>(
    result buildResult: @autoclosure () -> Result)
    -> ServerUploadingEndEvent<Result>
{
    ServerUploadingEndEvent(
        param1: ...,
        result: buildResult()
    )
}
```

you can call it your code using `as` as a generic function specializer (see `// (*)`)

```
serverLoadingEventsNotifier.notifyServerLoadingCompleted(
    anyServerLoadingEndEvent(
        result: ServerLoadingCompletedResult(...)
    ) as ServerLoadingEndEvent<ServerLoadingCompletedResult> // (*)
)

serverUploadingEventsNotifier.notifyServerUploadingFailed(
    anyServerUploadingEndEvent(
        result: ServerUploadingFailedResult(...)
    ) as ServerUploadingEndEvent<ServerUploadingFailedResult> // (*)
)
```