# How do I call a generic Swift function when none of the arguments provides the generic type?

Tags: swift, generics

The following compiles in the Swift REPL:

```
var m: [String:AnyObject] = [:]
func f<T: AnyObject>(s: String) {
    m[s] = T.self
}
```

However, if I naively try to invoke `f()`, thus:

```
let s: String = "foo"
class Foo {}
f<Foo>(s)
```

I get this error:

```
repl.swift:7:1: error: cannot explicitly specialize a generic function
f<Foo>(s)
^
repl.swift:7:2: note: while parsing this '<' as a type parameter bracket
f<Foo>(s)
 ^
```

If I try it without "explicitly specializing"...

```
f(s)
```

Swift decides I'm trying to do something even weirder, and I get:

```
repl.swift:7:1: error: cannot convert the expression's type 'String' to type '()'
f(s)
^~~~
```

Meanwhile, however, if I define a new function `g()` as follows:

```
func g<T: AnyObject>(s: String, t: T) {
    m[s] = T.self
}
```

and pass in a dummy `Foo` instance:

```
g(s, Foo())
```

it works fine:

```
> m
$R0: [String : AnyObject] = {
  [0] = {
    key = "foo"
    value = {
      instance_type = {}
    }
  }
}
```

So is there a reason Swift lets me define `f()` in the first place? And once defined, is there any way to invoke it?

---

**ETA:** I'm aware it's also possible to define a function `h<T: AnyObject>(s: String, t: T.Type)` that takes the type explicitly. It's the fact that Swift allows me to define the implicit version that I find questionable.

Comment: Just for the record, another workaround is to return `T`. Like:  `func g<T: AnyObject>(s: String) -> T {...}` now by casting it  `func(s) as Foo`  our immature swift compiler will deduce its type, so no need to pass is explicitly :(

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965439/cannot-explicitly-specialize-a-generic-function

Comment: Also this guy had the same problem https://twitter.com/dangerdave/status/490385202170982401

Comment: Bug reported [rdar://20583619](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6185198710423552)

Answer (score 4):

Differently from other languages, you cannot explicitly specify the generic type with a syntax like this:

```
f<Foo>(s)
```

instead the actual type is inferred via a parameter or the return type. In your case you are not providing a way for type inference to figure out what `T` is. And sadly I'm not aware of any way to use that function.

My suggestion is to explicitly pass the type of `T`:

```
func f<T: AnyObject>(s: String, type: T.Type) {
    m[s] = type
}

...

f(s, Foo.self)
```

Comment: I already knew that was an option, but thanks. My real question is why Swift lets me declare the less-verbose form and how it Apple expects me to call it.

Comment: That might just fall in the "bug" category ;-)

Comment: Agreed; or at least "yes, it's possible to write code that doesn't do what you think it should without getting an error." It would be nice if the compiler caught such possibilities, but it doesn't. That doesn't mean Swift wants you to do that, any more than it wants you to dereference a nil Optional, even though it allows it.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good comparison. In the general case, the compiler can't know at compile time the Optional is going to be nil. (Occasionally it can, and I would expect a good, mature IDE to detect that by static analysis and warn me.) Here, we're not talking about code that doesn't do what I think it should, we're talking about code that (as far as I can tell) can't ever do anything.