# Store generic Arrays in NSUserDefaults

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to store a generic Array in NSUserDefaults but I get the following error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Array<T>' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'`.

How can I solve this problem?

```
public class PropertyStore {   
    private let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    public func loadSet<T>(key: String) -> Set<T>? {
        guard let array = userDefaults.objectForKey(key) as? [T] else {
            return nil
        }

        return Set<T>(array)
    }

    public func saveSet<T>(key: String, value: Set<T>) {
        let array = Array(value)
        userDefaults.setObject(array, forKey: key) // <- ERROR
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @lucasD said, T needs to conform to NSCoding atleast. So the code looks like this.

```
     public func saveSet<T: NSCoding>(key: String, value: Set<T>) {
       let array = Array(value)
       userDefaults.setObject(array, forKey: key)
    }
```

However, this will not work for many reasons like:

```
   public func loadSet<T: NSCoding>(key: String) -> Set<T>? {
    guard let array = userDefaults.objectForKey(key) as? [T] else {
        return nil
    }

    return Set<T>(array)
   }

  let defaults = PropertyStore()
  defaults.saveSet("array", value: [1,2,3])
  ///defaults.loadSet<Int>("array")  ===> Cannot explicitly specialize a function
  ///defaults.loadSet("array")     ===> Cannot infer Type T
  //let a: Set<Int>? = defaults.loadSet("array")  ==> T cannot be inferred
```

In the case of `loadSet` type T cannot be inferred properly because we cannot specify it from outside, as far as i know. I would first try to return NSObject or `Set<AnyObject> or Set<NSCoding>` and then type cast it explicitly. Let me know if theres a better way though.

You can take a look at this SO post for more information on why a generics parameter cannot be specialised from outside. [SO Generics specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965439/cannot-explicitly-specialize-a-generic-function)

Answer (score 0):

You should define `T` as `NSCoding` conforming class. So when you're going to store the array, you are going to store an array of `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveDataWithRootObject()` results. Then, to return a `Set<T>` in the `loadSet` method, you should `unarchive` all the objects:

```
let storedData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults. ...
return storedData.flatMap { return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData($0) }
```

Comment: But if I have a `Set<String>` this wont be for example `Set<T: NSCoding>` compliant.

Comment: So try to accept every `T` and try to check the type of `T` inside your method