# Generic paramater could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, generics, alamofire

Here I have a function that creates a DataResponseSerializer with a generic type called *T*

```
extension DataResponseSerializer {
     static func mappableObjectSerializer<T: Mappable>() -> DataResponseSerializer<T> {...}
}
```

And another extension with a function to do the request, which returns a generic type called *SuccessObjectType*, in this one I call the function above.

```
public extension DataRequest { 
      @discardableResult func requestObject<SuccessObjectType: Mappable>(onSuccess success: @escaping  ((SuccessObjectType?) -> Void),
                      onFailure failure: @escaping ((NSError?) -> Void),
                      onCompletion completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> Self {

    let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<SuccessObjectType>.mappableObjectSerializer()

    return response(queue: nil, responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: { (response) in
        switch response.result {...})
}

}
```

The idea is to disassociate the serializer from the request itself, so I can implement UnitTest on a legacy project, but for some reason I get the error

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

On the line:

```
let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<SuccessObjectType>.mappableObjectSerializer()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this answer [Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965439/cannot-explicitly-specialize-a-generic-function) I could find a way around it, it's pretty straight forward, from this:

```
let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<SuccessObjectType>.mappableObjectSerializer()
```

To this:

```
let responseSerializer: DataResponseSerializer<SuccessObjectType> = DataResponseSerializer<SuccessObjectType>.mappableObjectSerializer()
```

What it does is to type cast the expected return from the function, this way the compile knows what to expect from the function.