# cannot specialize a non-generic definition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics

I have tried following [Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965439/cannot-explicitly-specialize-a-generic-function/43422710) and I can't get a hold of this

This is my code

```
class A<T>{
    func test(){
        self.verify(value : T.self)
    }
    
    func verify<T>(value: T) {
        print("Default")
    }
}

extension A where T == String {
    func verify<T>(value: T){
        print("Str")
    }
}



let o = A<String>()
o.test()
```

The test is the only available function that can be called. When I'm executing this, I get
Default not Str.

But according to the generics, I should get Str. What am I doing wrong here? What should I do to keep extension A give me Str if T == String

Comment: `func verify<T>(value: T)` the generic type T of the verify method has no relation with the class generic T

Comment: In your class you say T can be anything and the same in the first verify function and String fits that requirement. It is not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I want to call verify within test., I hoped that based on the type of T, it would go to the corresponding statically dispatched declaration of verify. But it does not. How can I call verify inside test and behave appropriately to T

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm learning generics new here. And this is what I got,

```
class A<T>{
     func test(){
        print("Def Test")
     
        verifyVal()
    }
    
    func verify() {
        print("Default verifyVal")
    }
}

extension A where T == String {
    func test(){
        print("String")
    }
}
extension A where T == Int {
    func test(){
        print("Int")
    }
}



let o = A<String>()
o.test()

let a = A<Int>()
a.test()
```

This will give you the expected result

```
String
Int
```

So basically overload the test method instead of verify.
However, there are some caveats

1. If the method test is inherited from another class , say A is a child of N where the method test was originally written, there is no way you can override it in the extensions.

Thats it.